# zbar not compatiable with MacBook Pro M1?

Tags: python, zbar

I'm trying to create a Python barcode reading app using pyzbar.

https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/ notes that the zbar shared library needs to be separately installed.

```
brew install zbar
```

I initially got the following error that the library couldn't be found.

```
ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library
```

and then I tried to manually link to the library using

```
$ mkdir ~/lib
$ ln -s $(brew --prefix zbar)/lib/libzbar.dylib ~/lib/libzbar.dylib
```

now I get the following error error

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zbar/0.23.90_1/lib/libzbar.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Is the problem that this library is not compatible with M1? Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you run `pip install pyzbar && pip install pyzbar[scripts]`?

Comment: yes. pyzbar is installed as well.

Comment: I suggest you open an issue on [github](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/issues), and mention that it is not a duplicate of [#37](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/issues/37) as you have done the `brew` installation